# SLSQP in NLOPT fails for high condition number quadratic function

Tags: c++, mathematical-optimization, numerical-methods, nlopt

I am benchmarking the SLSQP algorithm with a simple 10D quadratic function:

[image: f(x) = x_1^2 + 10^6\sum\limits_{i=2}^{D}x_i^2]

The c++ function is:

```
double myfunc(const std::vector<double> &x, std::vector<double> &grad, void *)
{
    ++counter;
    assert(x.size() == 10);
    double y      = pow(x[0], 2);
    double factor = 1e6;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < 10; ++i) 
        y += factor * pow(x[i], 2);
    if (!grad.empty())
    {
        assert(grad.size() == 10);
        grad[0] = 2 * x[0];
        for (size_t i = 1; i < 10; ++i)
            grad[i] = 2 * factor * x[i];
    }
    return y;
}
```

To my suprise, SLSQP fails for this simple function, but if I switch algorithm to `nlopt::LD_LBFGS`, nlopt still optimize the function efficiently.

Could anyone please explain why SLSQP fails for this demo function?

The version of NLOPT is 2.4.2(given by `nlopt::version`), below is the full code:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <nlopt.hpp>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
mt19937_64 engine(random_device{}());
static int counter = 0;
double myfunc(const std::vector<double> &x, std::vector<double> &grad, void *)
{
    ++counter;
    assert(x.size() == 10);
    double y      = pow(x[0], 2);
    double factor = 1e6;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < 10; ++i) 
        y += factor * pow(x[i], 2);
    if (!grad.empty())
    {
        assert(grad.size() == 10);
        grad[0] = 2 * x[0];
        for (size_t i = 1; i < 10; ++i)
            grad[i] = 2 * factor * x[i];
    }
    return y;
}
int main()
{
    nlopt::opt opt(nlopt::LD_LBFGS, 10);

    std::vector<double> lb(10, -100);
    std::vector<double> ub(10, 100);
    opt.set_lower_bounds(lb);
    opt.set_upper_bounds(ub);
    opt.set_min_objective(myfunc, NULL);
    opt.set_maxeval(1000);
    // opt.add_inequality_constraint(myfunc_constr, nullptr, 1);

    vector<double> x(10);
    uniform_real_distribution<double> distr(-100, 100);
    for (auto &vx : x) 
        vx = distr(engine);
    double minf = 1e20;
    vector<double> fake_grad;
    cout << "f(x0) =    " << myfunc(x, fake_grad, nullptr) << endl;

    try
    {
        counter = 0;
        nlopt::result result = opt.optimize(x, minf);
        cout << "exit val:  " << result << endl;
    }
    catch (runtime_error &err)
    {
        cerr << err.what() << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "optimized: " << minf << endl;
    cout << "counter:   " << counter << endl;
    cout << opt.get_algorithm_name() << endl;

    int maj, min, bugf;
    nlopt::version(maj, min, bugf);
    cout << "version: " << maj << "." << min << "." << bugf << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In what sense exactly does it fail ?

Comment: @Fanfan If I change the `factor` in `myfunc` to 1e5, it sometimes give roundoff-limit failure, sometimes, it just gives nlopt-failure(the generic error code). If `factor` is set to 1e6, then it always gives nlopt-failure.

Comment: Poor scaling is one of the major reasons why NLP solver fail to solve models. Some NLP solvers can do some form of scaling (for NLP problems is more difficult than for LPs as the Jacobian matrix is not constant).

Comment: I thought as SQP is a quasi-newton method, and I used analytical gradient, scaling shouldn't affect the result heavily, maybe I was wrong.